# Modules/Extensions installed via Composer Problem

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, composer, third-party-module

I've installed Magento 1.9.3 locally on my computer and then installed a couple of extensions via composer.

Modules/Extensions are Fontis Australia Post and Better404

They seem to have installed OK, I can see them in the folders and in *admin/System/Advanced/Modules Output*.

BUT I cannot see them anywhere else in admin to enable them.

Comment: Clear your cache on the system.  Also, what does the readme say of your extension?  Sometimes it wants you to run certain commands.  Post in your question with this if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a composer installer with symlink strategy, i.e. the files and directories are in `vendor`, but symlinked into the Magento directory structure. This works well, **except** that Magento does not render templates behind symlinks by default. You have to allow symlinks explicitly in *System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer* so see output of the composer modules.